# Test classes in Groovy don't see test classes in Kotlin

Tags: gradle, groovy, kotlin

I have gradle project with Kotlin plugin.

In my project I uses groovy and Spock for tests.
One of utility classes used in tests in written in Kotlin and I put it to src/test/kotlin

I'm trying to use this class from groovy tests (Spock specification), I see that "compileTestKotlin" task runs first and compiles my utility class, but still "compileTestGroovy" fails, because it does not see it.

How can I fix this situation?
How to add build/classes/kotlin/test/ to the compilation classpath of groovy tests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that by default `compileTestGroovy` doesn't include `build/classes/kotlin/test` folder, so your Kotlin util class cannot be seen from Groovy tests.

In order to fix it you can manually add Kotlin test sources to `compileTestGroovy`'s classpath. Add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
compileTestGroovy.classpath += files(compileTestKotlin.destinationDir)
// in more recent versions it must be
compileTestGroovy.classpath += files(compileTestKotlin.destinationDirectory)
```

If your build file is `build.gradle.kts`, add the following

```
// make groovy test code depend on kotlin test code
tasks.named<GroovyCompile>("compileTestGroovy") {
    classpath += files(tasks.compileTestKotlin)
}
```